# Most performant way to update a single document in Elasticsearch via an alias

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch setup with an alias that points to many indices. I need to update a single document, but I don't know which index it resides in.

There are two ways I can accomplish this as far as I can see:

1. _update_by_query:

```
POST my-alias/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": ["my-id-to-update"]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['Field'] = 'new value'"
  }
}
```

2. read (which returns the specific index) then write:

```
GET my-alias/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": ["my-id-to-update"]
    }
  }
}

POST my-index-returned-from-the-get/_update/my-id-to-update
{
  "doc": {
    "Field": "new value"
  }
}
```

Which method is more performant?

Which method is preferred?

Is there a better way than either of these two?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of both approach will be the same with one difference that your first approach only need to send one request compare to second one with two request, so it would be better to use first approach as you will reduce the API calls by half.
Also in my opinion the first approach is much cleaner and fits more in concept of aliases of Elasticsearch because you are encapsulating exact index name from your application, as application doesn't need to have any clue about exact index-name your documents are in.

An important note about updating a document in Elasticsearch is documents in Elasticsearch don't get updated, it means the document will be flagged as deleted and new document will be created (this is due to Lucene implementation), then during process of Lucene `segment merging` the document will be actually deleted.
you can find a good blog post about segment merging [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html).